# Excel VBA Autofilter Compile Error?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a search box that Autofilters as you type. I have used a variety of tutorials but I am struggling to get it working correctly.

The code I am using is:

```
Private Sub SearchField_Change()
If Len(SearchField.Value) = 0 Then
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
Else
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Sheet1.Range ("A:A" & Rows.Count) .AutoFilter _ Field:= 1, Criteria1:="*" & SearchField.Value & "*"
End If
End Sub
```

I am receiving a Syntax error when I try to use this, what I find confusing is that I am copying what is on tutorials (changing the sheet names/textbox names as appropriate) yet no success.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the filter range correctly. The first cell in the range which is being filtered should be your header. So if the `headers` are in `Row 2`, try it like this...

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & SearchField.Value & "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is in that:

```
Range("A:A" & Rows.Count)
```

Which would try referencing some "A:A1000000" range, which is obviuolsly an error

Then you want to use:

```
Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count)
```

Or, which is the same:

```
Range("A:A")
```

But I wouldn't reference the whole column and limit the range to the actually “used” one

So you may try this little refactoring of your code:

```
Private Sub SearchField_Change()
    With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If Len(SearchField.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:= 1, Criteria1:="*" & SearchField.Value & "*"
    End With
End Sub
```